# How to show particular textbox border red color if i enter invalid email or blank in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, email

I have been created four email textboxes and also "more" link.

If i click more link, it shows one more textbox at each link.

Now i am struggling with show error status when i enter invalid email or blank field. 
Here is my code:

```
<input onclick="ValidateEmail()" style="float:right;" id="nextbutton" name="" type="submit" value="Next" />
```

Javascript:

```
var container = $(document.createElement('div')).css({
            padding: '5px', margin: '0'});

        $(container).append('<input type=text class="input" id="tb1" placeholder="Email" />');
        $(container).append('<input type=text class="input" id="tb2" placeholder="Email" />');
        $(container).append('<input type=text class="input" id="tb3" placeholder="Email" />');
        $(container).append('<input type=text class="input" id="tb4" placeholder="Email" />');
        $('#main').before(container);   // ADD THE DIV ELEMENTS TO THE "main" CONTAINER.

        var iCnt = 4;

    function IsValidEmail(email) {
                var expr = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
                return expr.test(email);
            };
            function ValidateEmail() {
                var email = document.getElementById("tb1").value;
                if (!IsValidEmail(email)) {
                    document.getElementById('tb1').style.border = "solid 1px red";
                  return false;
            }
```

I need to show red color textbox, in which particular filed is blank or invalid email.

May i know, how can i achieve this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JQuery's `keyup()` method on the `inputs` to validate the emails every time any char is entered or removed. If a specific email is invalid, add a css class `invalid` to its parent `div` (put every `input` in a separate `div`) and then you can color all `inputs` red that are children from a `div` marked as invalid (`.invalid input`). You may also add `labels` next to each input that are displayed only when their parent `div` is marked as invalid. These labels then contain an error message.

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u75vzjtm/) example.

HTML-Code:

```
<div id="main"></div>
<input id="nextbutton" name="" type="submit" value="Next" />
```

CSS:

```
.invalid input {
    background-color:#fee;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.invalid label {
    display:inline-block;
}

input {
    margin:5px;
    padding:2px;
    border:1px solid green;
}
label {
    display:none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var container = $(document.createElement('div')).css({
            padding: '5px', margin: '0'});

// add several <div><input ...><label>...</label></div>
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $(container)
        .append('<div><input type="text" class="input" id="tb'+i+'" placeholder="Email" /> <label>This email is invalid</label></div>');
}

$('#main').before(container);   // ADD THE DIV ELEMENTS TO THE "main" CONTAINER.

// Validate input on every keyup()-event
$("input", container).keyup(function() {
    validateEmail($(this));
});

var iCnt = 4;

function isValidEmail(email) {
    var expr = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    return expr.test(email);
}

function validateEmail(el) {
    if (!isValidEmail($(el).val())) {
        $(el).parent().addClass('invalid');
        return false;
    } else {
        $(el).parent().removeClass('invalid');
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You asked how to color inputs with invalid emails and the jsfiddle shows that, it's not much different from your code. Whenever any email input is changed, the `keyup()` event fires for that input and calls `validateEmail()`. That function then checks whether the email looks valid. If it isn't, it adds a css class `invalid`. If it is valid, it removes the css class `invalid`. CSS then colors all inputs with the class `invalid` in red and all that don't have that class in green. I also added `label` elements as error messages that pop up whenever an email is invalid.

Comment: Now, when i entering input email, it shows error status and also works next button.. i need after click the "next" button, then only show error status, and it shouldn't go next page.. thanks.